# How to hide Shipping Method prices

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods

Looking to hide the prices of every shipping method on the onepage checkout. Where is this content dynamically loaded? I've looked in and edited *app/design/frontend/theme/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml* but to no avail. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the shipping price for onepage checkout is loaded in the app/design/frontend/base/default/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml. By default lines 59-64 are related to showing shipping price.

Also if you want to hide the shipping price on the side bar/progress bar you can find the code in app/design/frontend/base/default/checkout/onepage/progress/shipping_method.phtml

Please keep in mind good theming practices and dont edit these files directly. You can find a lot of information about that on the web.